# Golang NIST P256 ARM64 ASM p256OrdMul/p256OrdSqr Montgomery Multiplication

Tags: montgomery-multiplication

In go/src/crypto/internal/nistec/p256_asm_arm64.s Line 448 / 473 / 498 / 524, We can see the code mul Ord with **hlp1** but NOT **hlp0**. According Montgomery Multiplication, shouldn't we mul Ord with **hlp0**?

```
    // First reduction step
    MUL acc0, hlp1, hlp0

    MUL const0, hlp1, t0
    ADDS    t0, acc0, acc0
    UMULH   const0, hlp0, t1

    MUL const1, hlp0, t0
    ADCS    t0, acc1, acc1
    UMULH   const1, hlp0, y0

    MUL const2, hlp0, t0
    ADCS    t0, acc2, acc2
    UMULH   const2, hlp0, acc0

    MUL const3, hlp0, t0
    ADCS    t0, acc3, acc3

    UMULH   const3, hlp0, hlp0
    ADC $0, hlp0

    ADDS    t1, acc1, acc1
    ADCS    y0, acc2, acc2
    ADCS    acc0, acc3, acc3
    ADC $0, hlp0, acc0
```

[image: Word-by-Word Montgomery Multiplication (WW-MM)]

((const0 x hlp1) mod 2^64 + acc0) >> 64 = ((const0 x hlp0) mod 2^64+acc0) >> 64,
**How to prove that this equation holds**？